# JSON File Parsing procedure for those field that not has in every array

Tags: java, json

Like, I have a json file

```
    "ref": [{
        "af": [
            1
         ], 
         "speaker": true, 
         "name": "Fahim"
     }, 
     {
         "aff": [
            1
          ],
          "name": "Grewe"
     }]
```

During parsing time, If a field is not available in every array(like here speaker). It should throw Null Pointer Exception. So, what are the procedure for parsing those field that not has in every array.

Comment: Just check if it's null, before doing anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

A nice JSON parsing library like this one will have different levels of validation :

https://code.google.com/p/quick-json/

you can set custom validation rules, or use a non-validating version which will just parse without checking standards etc.

Comment: Scroll down to 'quick-json Validating parser Usage' in that link - you can choose whether it will throw an exception or not for missing tags that should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
var ref = YourObject.ref;
for(var i=0; i<ref.length; i++){
    if(ref[i].speaker!==null){
        //do something
    }
}
```